# Uploadify and PHP move files issue

Tags: php, javascript, upload, directory, uploadify

I have created a script that will upload files to a general uploads folder, the upload works fine however when I try to get the script to move the files from the temp folder to the uploads folder. I get the following issue.

```
[23-Mar-2012 18:57:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/var/tmp/php3O42Kn' to '/home3/***/***/***/MAINFOLDER/uploads/itworks/' in /home3/***/***/***/MAINFOLDER/admin/uploader.php on line 21
```

When I had the uploads folder in the same directory as the `uploader.php` script it was working, however I placed my `uploader.php` script in the `/admin` folder while keeping the `/uploads` in the root folder. Below is the script I am using.

**uploader.php** (main/admin)

```
  <?php

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];


        $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
        $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $filename;


        // $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
        // $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
        // $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
        // $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

        // if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$typesArray)) {
                if (!file_exists($targetPath)) {  
                     mkdir(str_replace('//','/',$targetPath), 0755, true);  
                }

            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
            echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
        // } else {
        //  echo 'Invalid file type.';
        // }
    }
    ?>
```

**upload.php** (main/admin)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#file_upload").uploadify({
            'uploader'     : 'includes/uploadify.swf',
            'script'         : 'uploadify.php',
            'folder'         : '../uploads',
            'cancelImg'      : 'includes/images/cancel.png',
            'multi'          : true,
            'auto'           : false,
            'fileTypeExts'        : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
            'fileTypeDesc'       : 'Image Files (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG)',
            'queueID'        : 'custom-queue',
            'queueSizeLimit' : 10,
            'simUploadLimit' : 3,
            'sizeLimit'   : 10240000,
            'removeCompleted': true,
            'onAllComplete'  : function(stats) {
                $('#status-message').text(data.filesUploaded + ' files uploaded, ' + data.errors + ' errors.');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I think the issue is here: `'folder'         : '../uploads',`. Idealy I want the uploader.php file to automatically push the directory back one level however all my methods seem not to have worked.

Many thanks to anyone who could help me shed some light on this!

Comment: This error could come from a number of issues. Are you sure the directories exist from the path you are accessing them from?

Comment: make sure the folder you are copying into has the correct permissions

Comment: Have you double checked the permissions on the directory you are moving from and moving to? Remember that whatever user the web server or PHP process is running as needs write access to both.

Comment: what is your directory structure at the moment, is it root -> main -> admin ?

Comment: My current directory layout is as follows main with two subfolders: admin and then uploads. So main -> admin. main -> uploads

Comment: Ok are both the main folders at the same level ?

Comment: @Johnny Craig so I should set permissions on the uploads folder and admin folder respectively?

Comment: This is not to do with permissions as i initially thought also. You create that directory if it doesn't exist with full read/write permissions. It has to do with how you access the uploads folder.

Comment: even if you create the directory with PHP you need to set permissions, or you cannot copy images into it.(at least on my Mac server)  Use: `mkdir("uploads/", 0777);`

Comment: Johnny read the code please, he does do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be one of the following depending on how far root is from the current admin directory.

```
'../../uploads'
```

or

```
'../../../uploads
```

Comment: It's only going back one directory. So it should just be "../" correct?

Comment: Attached is a screenshot of my current structure (messy I know, I'll clean that up later) http://cl.ly/FGSb

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Have you tried just straight up `uploads` instead of `../uploads` ? Because as you see you're concatinating the document root to the folder path, so i don't think there's a need for going up one level. Either remove `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or change `../uploads` to `uploads` and see if it works.

Comment: I tried it and it created a directory in the admin folder so admin/uploads/testa No file was placed inside the testa folder and the following error was shown:


    [Undefined variable: filename in /admin/uploadify.php on line 9
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /admin/uploadify.php on line 22
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/var/tmp/phpLWWnLe' to '/admin/files/testb/' in /admin/uploadify.php on line 22

Comment: HUZZAH, IT WORKS. Apparently I had deleted part of the script for the filename variable without knowing.

Comment: i was about to ask where filename is defined.

Comment: I probably would have never seen that without your probing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying current configuration if working fine then it should work with any folder.
But the issue could easily come from non-writable folder (did you check folder permissions?) to missing trailing slash in the "../uploads/".

Or as Interstellar_Coder has suggested maybe another set of '../' is missing.

Comment: The php script creates the directory alright (with permissions set to 777 for testing) in the main/uploads folder.

The problem is moving the file to it from temp.